# Can I save this Northfork Pine?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-recommendations, sunlight, recovery

[image]

I recently re-potted this guy to a pot thang would drain at the bottom and have moved him over the course of a few months to a spot that has more light. The color has continued to get darker and the tip are curling. When I reported it, I watered it throuoghly and haven’t watered it again. I have been listing it and have a humidifier going in the room now. Is there anything else I can do? Do you think it’ll make it?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when a Norfolk Island Pine branch tips start curling like that it indicates that at some time the root ball became too dry. If the foliage becomes crispy then it went too far into dryness, otherwise you are in with a chance.

It only takes one drought incident and might have occurred when you transplanted if there was a lot of damage to the root ball that left your tree top heavy, with too much foliage to be supported by the roots. If it continues to look unhappy but does not continue drying (in which case you will see many needles falling) you might consider pruning back the foliage by a quarter or so to allow the root to catch up again. Unlike regular pines the NI Pine responds well to careful pruning if it is still viable.

Probably better to have indirect light and not full sun until it has recovered its normal growth. The higher humidity will help a bit.